# Mostrar o maior e o menor número

Tags: javascript, matemática

Por que está errado?

```
var n1 = parseFloat(prompt("Digite um número:"));
var n2 = parseFloat(prompt("Digite um número:"));
var n3 = parseFloat(prompt("Digite um número:"));
function maiorDosTres(n1, n2, n3) {
  if ( n1 > n2 > n3) {
    alert( "O maior número é: " + n1 + " e o menor é: " + n3);
  } else if ( n1 > n3 > n2) {
    alert( "O maior número é: " + n1 + " e o menor é: " + n2);
  } else if ( n2 > n1 > n3) {
    alert( "O maior número é: " + n2 + " e o menor é: " + n3);
  } else if ( n2 > n3 > n1) {
    alert( "O maior número é: " + n2 + " e o menor é: " + n1);
  } else if ( n3 > n1 > n2) {
    alert( "O maior número é: " + n3 + " e o menor é: " + n2);
  } else if ( n3 > n2 > n1) {
    alert( "O maior número é: " + n3 + " e o menor é: " + n1);
  }
}
maiorDosTres(n1, n2, n3);
```

Comment: Já implementaram o Math.max(args) e o Math.min(args)

Comment: Eu não posso usar funções. E o problema é que quando eu executo, em vez de mostrar a string com o maior e menor número, mostra undefined.

Comment: Tem os operadores `&&` e `||` que podem ajudar vc a resolver isso. Falta algo na suas comparações :P

Comment: Obrigado. Ajudou muito.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 11):

Está errado porque você não pode comparar mais que dois operandos ao mesmo tempo. Isto não existe:

```
if ( n1 > n2 > n3) {
```

O correto seria:

```
if ( n1 > n2 && n2 > n3) {
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Operators/AndRange.js).

Desta forma você tem três expressões com dois operandos cada: `n1 > n2`, `n2 > n3` e a operação relacional `&&` que tem como operandos os resultados da expressões anteriores.

O mesmo vale para os demais. Acho que já pegou o jeito.

Tem maneiras melhores de fazer isto. Usar [`Math.max()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) e [`Math.min()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) seria uma delas. Não vou colocar porque me parece que você está fazendo isto para fins de estudo e não quer a melhor solução.

Answer (score 10):

Você pode utilizar as funções [`Math.max()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) e [`Math.min()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min). As duas funções recebem todos os valores para comparação como parâmetros. Apesar da a pergunta ser o motivo de estar errado, essa forma deixará o seu código mais enxuto.

```js
var n1 = 10;
var n2 = 5;
var n3 = 7;

var max = Math.max(n1, n2, n3);
var min = Math.min(n1, n2, n3);

var pre = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('pre'));
pre.textContent = 'dos valores ' + n1 + ', ' + n2 + ' e ' + n3;
pre.textContent += ' o máximo é ' + max + ' e o mínimo é ' + min;
```

Se os dados estiverem em um *array* utilize [`apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

```
var numeros = [4,6,2,7,9,5];
Math.max.apply(Math, numeros);
```

Comment: Math.max() e Math.min() é a maneira semanticamente correta/nativa para comparar valores. `+1`

Answer (score 1):

Grave os valores em um array e use o "for" para este caso, a função fica mais flexível e serve para qualquer número de argumentos:

```
var n = [1, 2, 3];


numero=n(i)

for (i = 0; i < n.length; i++) { 
    if (n(i) >= numero) { maior = n(i); }
    if (n(i) <= numero) { menor = n(i); }
}
alert( "O maior número é: " + maior + " e o menor é: " + menor);
```

Comment: Poderia explicar seu código? Fiquei curioso sobre o funcionamento.

Answer (score 1):

Por que não *ordenar* os números?

```
function maiorDosTres() {
    var a = Array.prototype.sort.call(arguments);
    alert( "O maior número é: " + a[a.length - 1] + " e o menor é: " + a[0]);
}
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fsg9xz99/)**</kbd>

Answer (score -3):

function maxEMim(n1, n2, n3){

```
var max = Math.max(n1,n2,n3);
var mim = Math.min(n1,n2,n3);

console.log(`Maior: ${max} e o menor: ${mim}`);
```

}

maxEMim(10,5,0);

Answer (score -3):

let n1 = 1;
let n2 = 5;
let n3 = 7;

let max = Math.max(n1,n2,n3);
let mim = Math.min(n1,n2,n3);

console.log(`Maior: ${max} e o menor: ${mim}`);